# Questions regarding identification of one-one and many-one functions

Tags: functions

I was going through my textbook and one of the topics was identifying one-one and many-one functions the first 2 methods described were quite easy, doing so anytically or drawing the graph of the function however the third method i did not quite understand, the method is given as follows,

If for a continuous function $f(x)$, derivative $f'(x) \geq 0$ or $f'(x) \leq 0 \forall x \in D_f$ then f(x) is one-one. It should be noted that the values of x for which $f'(x) = 0$ should not form a interval.

I quite did not understand why this method works tried relating it to visualising derivatives as a line which represents sloped however did not work.

Could anyone explain why this method works in identification of one-one and many-one functions?.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If derivative is more than 0, it means that the function is constantly increasing, and if derivative is negative then it's constantly decreasing. This means that there exists only a single pre image in the domain of corresponding to any f(x) value

Comment: @Gwen thanks for the response could you post is as an answer so that i can accept it

Comment: I'll give you a more detailed answer in the comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-one function, also known as an injective function, is defined as such a function that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ if $x_1=x_2$

This means each value found by solving the function has a single pre image in the domain of *f(x)*. So **if $x_2>x_1$**, there arise 2 cases:-

1. **It's an increasing function($f(x_2)>f(x_1)$)**

$f(x_2)>f(x_1) →f(x_2)-f(x_1)>0..(i) $
As $ x_2>x_1 → x_2-x_1 >0...(ii)$

Thus we divide (i) by (ii) to get

$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} >0→ f'(x)>0 $

2. **It's a decreasing function ($f(x_2)<f(x_1))$**

$f(x_2)<f(x_1) →f(x_2)-f(x_1)<0..(i) $
As $ x_2>x_1 → x_2-x_1 >0...(ii)$

Thus we divide (i) by (ii) to get

$\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} <0→ f'(x)<0 $

Also $f'(x)=0$ is possible, but its for a specific x value, and it holds true for that value only.But it will not be zero for an interval $[a,b],a<b$.As that implies f(x) stays constant for multiple x values, which is not possible in one-one functions.

**The value of *f(x)* for which *f'(x)=0* is known as the maxima (maximum value) or minima(minimum value) of the function**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The derivative is allowed to be $0$ at single points (e.g. $f(x)=x^3$ is a strictly increasing function but has $f'(0)=0$). The derivative should not be zero over any interval, cause then $f$ would be constant over that interval and therefore not one-to-one.

Comment: Yes thanks, I forgot to mention this, although this can be well understood from the definition of the function. Can I type what you had texted in my answer?

Comment: Sure, that's fine.